# Can you decrypt me? (Cops)

Tags: number, cops-and-robbers

## Can you decrypt me?

### Cops

Cops, post obfuscated code that hides a number \$n\$ (n must not be greater than the program length) inside its code. If \$n\$ chars are changed (no additions or deletions), the program outputs exactly one \$n\$ (any amount of whitespace before or after is allowed.) Otherwise, it outputs something else. Both programs may not error, and there can be multiple solutions.

### Example

```python
print(2)
```

N is 1.

---

Robbers' post:

```python
print(1)
```

### Scoring

For the cops, the user with the most uncracked posts wins. If there is a tie, the user with the total minimum byte count wins.

Comment: Should I tell in my answer which *n* I chose? Or should the robbers try to find it?

Comment: Cops should choose n, not the robbers.

Comment: You don't understand. Should `n` be told in the answer or should the robbers find it?

Comment: n should be told in the cops' answers and can be different for each cop.

Comment: Is there some time after which a cop answer is safe?

Comment: @CommandMaster If it survives for 7 days.

Answer (score 2):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 5204 bytes [Cracked (intended way also listed)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/269183/can-you-decrypt-me-robbers/269342#269342)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
string secret = "secret";
void f1(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1111111";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1111111";return;}}}}}}}}
void f2(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1111111";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1111111";return;}}}}}}}}
void f3(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1111111";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1111111";return;}}}}}}}}
void f4(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1111111";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1111111";return;}}}}}}}}
void f5(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1111111";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1111111";return;}}}}}}}}
void f6(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1111111";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1111111";return;}}}}}}}}
void f7(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1111111";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1111111";return;}}}}}}}}
int main() {
    f1();
    f2();
    f3();
    f4();
    f5();
    f6();
    f7();
    cout<<6;
    f1();
    f2();
    f3();
    f4();
    f5();
    f6();
    f7();
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7ZhNb6MwEIbv@RVuKm1BoauQD3ow7h@JOACBrMHYfFaqKL89O7YDC4dKPewFyT5E78zDjCfDeyIuy9dbHN/vz5THrLsmyKeiaeskLN43XUP5DfGwSJoyjBPUtFe8ASizTRLXSYsI2mq1xZsPQa8odS27p6mls79Zwm/tH8t@Ip7dx6JrfX/r6rPF8EBXczxQ3qLw4gWk11WXffD6gl6cR@QuosMiOi6i0yI6q2jAqagteQUle0z9M6a7nRoxvNDgncDvzg2@H25YlnuLcp/sv75UH6j5UQ8XehCAus2YzwgMgTNNsjnJSQYk1ySfE0ZyIEwTNicFYUAKTYo54aQAwjXh6o9ANlK7p07m5A5zCocPOBKCoc/wk6Qha5JphQLmF77l@r5nYzHvXAIpR1KOncOmK@Ta5CVajs9XoCvYZvXYpvglayvb7mXNDl5LFYAzUqucQKRApIAkqjmRWbuXo7Z1l@AIrJtrDjko@hc/qcS370ifh4sPxsXGxat38dG42Lh49S4@GRcbF6/exWfjYuPi1bvYMy42Ll69i9@Mi42LV@xitcCQcstG/QbBkV/dsFaHSR0ndZrUeVLepN5Gpa/18H9qOdzvfwE)

Same as my previous submission, hopefully it is a bit more radiation hardened.

\$n = 6\$.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269342/76323) but I'd like to know how you come up such puzzle

Comment: @l4m2 This puzzle was from Ali Gurel, where the idea is you want to select k numbers from {1 ... n} such that every other way to select k numbers would get a subset sum collision with you. His original version had k = 5. I did a very similar search as you you did to solve this problem using a naive O((n choose k)^2) way, and I realized with pruning you can do it much faster, so I could do k = 6. I noted that the solution is easier to verify than it is to compute and that's how I came up with this puzzle.

Comment: I actually ran it and take 497m15.544s. Imagine someone later do `int main() { printf("%d", f()^0); }` where solving `f` take long time

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 4960 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/269183/can-you-decrypt-me-robbers/269214#269214)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
string secret = "secret";
void f1(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1";return;}}}}}}}}
void f2(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1";return;}}}}}}}}
void f3(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1";return;}}}}}}}}
void f4(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1";return;}}}}}}}}
void f5(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1";return;}}}}}}}}
void f6(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1";return;}}}}}}}}
void f7(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1";return;}}}}}}}}
int main() {f1();f2();f3();f4();f5();f6();f7();cout<<6;f1();f2();f3();f4();f5();f6();f7();}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7ZjNbqMwEIDveQo3K7Wg0CpuG/YwuC8ScQACWfNj87tSRXn2dGwnLUiVdq9IziHyzOcZO@YTIiR1/XhOksvlFxdJOZxSEnDZ9W0aVW@boePiTERUpV0dJSnp@hNsEKpslyZt2hNGtma0hc1fyU8ko4478swx2acyFef@j@PeMd8dEzn0QbClW0A0tAImLnoSHf2QjWb@cR8@PpAH7xrRRfS8iF4W0esiOuhogky2jlqCsz3w4AB8t9Obi448fGP4vaPhT9ualoX@ojBg@48P3YFS@o9qitUMp5kGt3zOcGHIDcnnpGA5ksKQYk5KViApDSnnpGIlksqQak4Eq5AIQ4T@CZiN9XlzL/cKr/QqT0wQS1mS9@idZVHZpV/HJnH/MnBoEPguyHnnGkl9I/Wtc9QNlTowtYgZ3uY3OG7wHJvrOcp7Vdu47qhqdngpmhBtyJz6C8QaxBooopszlXVHtdW@HVKIUdTCcMxh0Xd8pxM/XB3zudr6bG21tq7G1hdrq7V1Nba@Wlutraux9WBttbauxlbf2mptXY2tv62t1tYV2KqPLuLCccmoXmSBej8A6m8XqKdZUA8JoO69oJQG08iH/5g6XS6f)

Intended solution only modifies the characters in secret, and also takes very long to run.

The hidden n is \$6\$. If unchanged, the program outputs \$111111161111111\$.

Comment: [I found an unintended solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269214/92727), but I'll try legitimately solving it too.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 669 bytes, \$n = 1\$, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269245/91267)

```python
import lzma
exec(lzma.decompress(b'\xe0\x00E\x00A]\x004\x9bJg\xb8R<s\xda\xb0\xe5\xbe\xe9\xde\t\x02\x8d\x9d\x02LW\x8bw\x87\xf3mkn1\xc5\xd9\xd6\xe9\xc9E\xf25\xd3\xd7\x01\x91\xc2FM4\xe5sW\xd6\xaaR\x07j\xe7\xa3\x80\x05b\xfcZ9\x0en5\xc2\x00\x01\x00\x00r\x00\xe0\x00\x86\x00y]\x002\x9d\x88\xce\xe12k^\xffi\x8eN\xf1\x83j-\xf5\\\x86\xd9\x01\xb6\xban\xb5_B\xcb@\xeeZ\x05u\x9c,a\xf3\xd1\xf5y\x96\xd0\xf6\x11\x82y\x13\x9cUb:j\x13\xa72\xccl_J\x90*\xf0\x1b[t\x84\xcb\xad\xff>qg\xf7\xe7\x93L\x04\x8fT\x91\xfe\xc9\xd1\x84]\x9f\xcd\xa6\x9e3W[\xbb\xcb/A\xbbZr\x9fq\xf5Wj\xe4\xe0\\\xadt)\xea\xee\xa7]\x80A1\x04\x8e\x9aM\x00', format=lzma.FORMAT_RAW, filters=[{'id': lzma.FILTER_LZMA2}]))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NVJda9tAEIQ-9lf4zXFJWn3Gp9CUqpBAg92CcBHY55o76a61Y9mOpBC5pb-kBPKS_Kj8ms740gfdjlYzu7Or-_u027c_t5uHh8fb1p6I51f3y2q3rdve-lelXpvOFEdEb0tTbKtdbZrmSPdlZzzZed4Fj3TOM5Jdoq9-yE6L7H0ju1IBgmRiRIOYIGdkC24gO1GCXhKPcrzpOxxD2dmwut74sisgKik4dcIiQScbMBviAdMDKyEzuBxH7NLkjq5Uhq_DFXKgKdAFrcYaBYopanlmE1NH067OIXq1A24wqE4Z94fZAmdWCOg4ih9cf0c5u0TOfAFCERGuToBiKZ2W9llcA2u1wREvPkGvP6KAmdLSLcoWx4pjg-9TvUeKYhiwiD4LB0j6Ibnf9NnKYTWEp6JYL66Q996ADYWvZ1iviNgFlJIWP9zgl9ih20YSjtAX34WduPVZw-W67iLCsIlFAkqF7okJ8xmMaxZ8lxJNa1JuaDXniqPDwiS7tQNgxeFob869p_5LO6QSNeYq-8c9u60r1Z4fbtXl12ycThZZmiO_XLembs5nv_vLsn_Wc4TPo8lFthhNx2nwZz4YuFv6cln_X9p_)

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269245/76323

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 49 bytes, n=49, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269287/76323)

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fm0Sg9/8/AA)

Saturate question

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269287/92901)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 723 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269202/91472)

```python
P=3
p=[i*(P+1)+1*(i//2)for i in range(P)]
v=[(p[2]*(p[1]+1)+1)+(p[1]-1)*i for i in p]
I=[x*2-1+(v[2]-v[1]+1)*(i//2)for i,x in enumerate(v[::-1])]
t=[vars(__builtins__)[dir(__builtins__)[i]]for i in I]
m='_'.join(vars(t[0])[dir(t[0])[i]].__name__ for i in v)
M=vars(__builtins__)[dir(__builtins__)[v[2]+1]](''.join(x.__name__[:len(t)-i]for i,x in enumerate(t)))
l=t[2](M,m[2:v[1]-v[0]+1]+m[v[2]-v[1]+t[1](t[0](v[2])[-1]):])[-1::-1]
PP=[len(dir(t[2]))-p[2]-1,len(m),sum(len(dir(x))for x in t)//sum(p)+len(p)-1,I[1]%(len(dir(t[1]))+len(dir(t[2]))),sum(p)-1,sum(I)//sum(v)+len(p)-1,sum(p)-1,p[2],I[1]%(len(dir(t[1]))+len(dir(t[2]))),v[2]-v[0]-len(v)-1]
print(len(vars(t[0])[dir(t[0])[sum(PP[:P])]](t[0](),[l[i-1]for i in PP])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVK9boMwEN55CpYqPsAhJEuF5AdgiOTdsiyq0tYVOBZxEH166jMUoipDFmP5vp@777A/7utiTq@2nybOTpFlQieEpwWkRUJ0nh/h49LHOtYm7mvz2RAOMhqYIFYcZeLPQgYwpOFOC0h0vFKsjComxuRIi5QMnkGHmXCvnY0Ibcyta/raNR5XlrSQ3scxMdT9lSj1dtOt0@aqFIh33f970VKulpWMOrZTu/33RRsS6E4c5Eybbx6@V8rUXaPU1usA0Zk9ZYeDpIWUZLe4jKucKNvGEAdUy4ezOQCIWua8AjlnnTiWGIhP5YCKaSe2kJw/QsMhOBAYSRm@IZ6IcybQbJ7LI4DiTmiR4WsH2fXWkT/ACCHr0I2DPMeahRTLFjyl8mYvZJPzXnN1U58FAxov1aIy3KmsAGzkOc1l3oOkWBkAJ7O9Ni4QH64PXTgXJfe/yJIQZKIV2nPXbXKO8tP0Cw)

The hidden \$n\$ is \$9\$. If unchanged, the program outputs \$10\$.

Comment: Cracked without understanding any of the intended obfuscation: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269202/53748 (I think this may be a persistent problem with this challenge, and that it is hard to write a good cop post.)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 651 bytes, \$n=2\$, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269275/76323)

```python
print(77925340277363824169293758807642437284508406489944233814731817114744334387054677199464359370358303681225801571736917189241020964424020531423054738521455432784731931386377196234255749859141710848221995*7660297729448052594468076976871308901099050010752258215140275334247136696601489292003583235840730794856813394396865245853772202539436917905108732823263342134564638227230398268672502337581353160403575356676232895580244410109024495577929416391%997624712161309143295415334518642567808466476564516128021383833912794511198191262082650250977292178811713461440089160581066992373718706289075971369001597094521060013695658387955211810675571614035311614)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NZJbSl5BEIQhexFiINBd1dcNib4YCb8PrsEl5MUXXVRWY40XDpzpGWaqq76Zf28PT5fbP_cvL6-Pl5vf8__H88Pfu_vLz-5FMgzdLA7Ca7HsnLGuQLAxkTZhFbMbAXI8mj7eriKCDE5bRnW7tlQwJWHMobHGgRzzbFeP1alZ9THYluTU25IuXSk0J-GRGUTP6bJ0TvEoFxjI7NjJ9ZCQbA2gnvmrqwzbDVkcS6TGOhm2a9pps-a2a2kaO48nePqJnkqA0KaqlYwrKBb2EQD6hTWtNyYVhtzg1lQiclLOABNDrZ5waiBbTQyIOsLOyIoDF62Q3IFON9KEUqCdil8WaicnWdUKitkUNESIlHyfSivnulZ3xPWrVbLjGl6KJyDEZvgJkz66u6weEaqKLjlI7YMkxVOfFKBI6e47rknBZEym0j4wwnvGBZlRHmECKJeya6K0YFMX2VZyKpx76K3QqjLJQts001qWKE7LPNzP6VYMWTl56ae4_nyTX0_z-4m-Aw)

Comment: It looks like changing the last two digits to `%3` works, is that intended?

Comment: @xnor Nope ): oh well

Comment: [6086 solutions found under some restriction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269275/76323)

Comment: Change the last two digits to `%7`

Answer (score 0):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 57 bytes, n=3, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269226/)

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fm0yg9/8/AA)

Seems this question hard to make sth interesting

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 873 bytes, \$n = 4\$, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/269183/can-you-decrypt-me-robbers/269265#269265)

```python
import lzma;exec(lzma.decompress(b'\xe0\x00\x86\x00\x7f]\x00\x05\t\x8c\x1f48\x17VAca7\xfc\xaf\xf6\xcd(?\xfa\x11\xf2f\x12\xa8\xe8\xd5\xeb!\x99\xe1\xe7\x81i\x94\x9ej\xf1\x95\x1f\xdd\x83\x11\x01\x84\xb8\xa9=\xe2\xa6\xe6\x88\x8b\xb0\x8a\xacWkV\xc4!\xb4\xaf\\c\xfa\xbc\xf9\xb1\xee\x04\'\xe7d0pJ3B\x02\xcbH\xa2u\r6\xe2>4\xb8\x8f\xe1\x99\x1bW\x8c\x0cT/\xd7wt.{_\x89\t\xb1Ws\xdc\x7f.\xcc\xd6\xb8\x0f\x874\x8eH\xb4\xccq\xb7UV\x00\x00\x01\x00\x004\x00\x01\x00\x18a85aa25882b90aaa356ebd56b\x00\x01\x00\x00c\x00\x01\x00\x006\x00\x01\x00\x005\x00\x01\x00\ndf940ede04a\x00\x01\x00\x003\x00\xe0\x00T\x00A]\x002\r\x88&\x926K\xd9\xf0vNM\xc8\xee\x93\xdfB\xf5\xf5t\x85\x88:\xf9\xa5\xe0\xeb`\xc4\xbdK\xf6s%\xe4\xdf\xae\x1a\xe1-\t\x91\xda\xab\xd0\x10\xea\xa1\x9d\xcd\xec\xe9\x95hD\xb8\xfb\x90\x8e\xe8\x9d\x99"\x14\x00\x00', format=lzma.FORMAT_RAW, filters=[{"id": lzma.FILTER_LZMA2}]).decode())
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVPbbtNAEH3gR0IkaCLRsHa89m5RQEGACm1AikIiwVZhr6qhaYLtgqHiS3jpC3wUX8OZbPrQPIx3fHbmzOzZ2d9_Nz-a8_Xlzc2fqyYcin_3ynK1WVdN5-LnSj_xrbc98gbO2_VqU_m67pkD1XqmWgYTeVyLcBYdxlUD2Ko2CZnAt5iPrS5UGwDpgBUZ1vWewdPYTrCmgJMU24j3MMexmvuqlRIOIjzyRVICyGD-M3KASk5FEO6wO4xcDCYQZECj5QipxIuSHiYACoNNahzFtV18maObDKVMtm1P2diXoRXVDVX34M0UnbpwbPNm-Bz_oLXmGDnplaqIP326KytCbJqaT8wiisHs7DE6Lb43g-slIEkqmWRRA7Qk3wB8cFweSRhIRAFG4Y9jc9Z-hVO8n-90ZvGw0c_uAonQgmudciFSI5nWeshzbxzPzX6m3QfyfYDfAS5dkBnzzrNM70cOoxNnY0af8XYqUlWR-A-hSZqf4JBQJrBvbyc4lYj6SuS6AGEDJ6MR4pRzFK9B80jrzSe6LwjhTmiU6gfAMkpFDGgSTdofkrgSbTm6ZBzZkSaUTv90NY5mEP84vZc0Secvou4B0ZLGw8dRpEgpu0i_lZgdPOqEdbXSzWj7MF69m07Gs-V0vABeXjS-qkcfr7ul6x51YsDr09nL6fL0w2Sc_jrrb1-S871-P7643cO7fYD_AQ)

This response is much like my [previous one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269227/91267) but with an increased \$n\$ to prevent direct brute-force attacks. Understanding the [crack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269245/91267) to the earlier version should aid in cracking this one.

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269265/76323

Answer (score 0):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 8271 bytes, \$n = 2\$, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269311/106959)

```
/~-/-~~//-~/~%--//-*///*\*/76543//~~~~~~~~~~~~%%%/***//~///*///%/4//-//~~~--********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************%%%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7csxCoBADAXR06QJhF@46mVsLAQLu@1z9TVaeQVhHiSkmPRr7@fRx1CGIlO1lBZRh0vyzbUuc5uk/DAzuVeQT1NjavXxRhEOAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB@z8zGuAE)

If unchanged, outputs:

```
444444444444444444444444765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543765437654376543444
```

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269311/25180)