# Can you decrypt me? (Robbers)

Tags: number, cops-and-robbers

## Can you decrypt me?

### Robbers

Find any combination of \$n\$ working chars to change and what they should change into, where \$n\$ is chosen by the cop. You cannot change less than n chars, only exactly \$n\$.

### Example

```python
print(2)
```

N is 1.

---

Robbers' post:

```python
print(1)
```

### Scoring

For the robbers, the user with the most cracks wins. If there is a tie, then it is a tie.

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 49 bytes, \$n = 49\$, cracks [@l4m2's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269272/92901)

```
"-[>->>-<<<---------]>-----"&console.log(196>>2.)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fSTfaTtfOTtfGxkYXBmLtwJSSWnJ@XnF@TqpeTn66hqGlmZ2dkZ7m//8A)

Polyglot with [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f9fSTfaTtfOTtfGxkYXBmLtwJSSWnJ@XnF@TqpeTn66hqGlmZ2dkZ7m//8A), just to keep things interesting.

Comment: My solution almost run out of bytes `-------[->--------<]>[->-<]>-[>->-<<-]>-----.>.--`

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), [by enzo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269188/53748) 723 bytes, n=9

Probably not as intended, but this works...

```python
P=3
p=[i*(P+1)+1*(i//2)for i in range(P)]
v=[(p[2]*(p[1]+1)+1)+(p[1]-1)*i for i in p]
I=[x*2-1+(v[2]-v[1]+1)*(i//2)for i,x in enumerate(v[::-1])]
t=[vars(__builtins__)[dir(__builtins__)[i]]for i in I]
m='_'.join(vars(t[0])[dir(t[0])[i]].__name__ for i in v)
M=vars(__builtins__)[dir(__builtins__)[v[2]+1]](''.join(x.__name__[:len(t)-i]for i,x in enumerate(t)))
l=t[2](M,m[2:v[1]-v[0]+1]+m[v[2]-v[1]+t[1](t[0](v[2])[-1]):])[-1::-1]
PP=[len(dir(t[2]))-p[2]-1,len(m),sum(len(dir(x))for x in t)//sum(p)+len(p)-1,I[1]%(len(dir(t[1]))+len(dir(t[2]))),sum(p)-1,sum(I)//sum(v)+len(p)-1,sum(p)-1,p[2],I[1]%(len(dir(t[1]))+len(dir(t[2]))),v[2]-v[0]-len(v)-1]
print(9)#xxxxxxt[0])[dir(t[0])[sum(PP[:P])]](t[0](),[l[i-1]for i in PP])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVLdboMgFL73KUyWpRyVWuzNZsIDeNGEe0KIy9zGopRYatzTO0CnTbOLeoGE8/2c84H5sV9nfXwx/TQxeowM5SpBLCWQkgSpPC/g49zHKlY67mv92SAGIhooR4YXInErEQEMadhjAomKV4oRUUX5mBSYpGhwDDzMhFvtbPTQRl@7pq9t43BliYlwPpbyoe4vSMq3q2qt0hcpgb@r/u5ECbFaViLq6E7u9t9npVGgW34QM23eOfheSl13jZRbrwNEJ/qQnR8kJUKg3eIyrnK8bBuNLGAl/p3NAkDUUusU0CnreFH6QFwqB6@YdnwLybolNByCA@4jKcM/xBMxRrk3m@dyCMD@TjDJ/GkH2eXaoT/ACCHr0I2FPPc1A6kvG3CUypk9o03Oec3VTX0WDGi/qRaV4UZlBfhGHtNc5j0I7CsD@MlMr7RFr/A0hu/@@rwLY7xk7oksCUHGW64cd71Nxrz8NP0C)

Comment: Cracked, I guess :(

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), cracks [l4m2's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269220/120591), 57 bytes, n=3

```
>++--+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fTltbV1ebdKD3/z8A)

I assume this is the intended one? n=3 doesn't offer many possiblilities.

Comment: Expected `[]` to skip some `+` but whatever

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 669 bytes [Mukundan314's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269227/76323)

```python
import lzma
exec(lzma.decompress(b'\xe0\x00E\x00A]\x004\x9bJg\xb8R<s\xda\xb0\xe5\xbe\xe9\xde\t\x02\x8d\x9d\x02LW\x8bw\x87\xf3mkn1\xc5\xd9\xd6\xe9\xc9E\xf25\xd3\xd7\x01\x91\xc2FM4\xe5sW\xd6\xaaR\x07j\xe7\xa3\x80\x05b\xfcZ9\x0en5\xc2\x00\x01\x00\x00/\x00\xe0\x00\x86\x00y]\x002\x9d\x88\xce\xe12k^\xffi\x8eN\xf1\x83j-\xf5\\\x86\xd9\x01\xb6\xban\xb5_B\xcb@\xeeZ\x05u\x9c,a\xf3\xd1\xf5y\x96\xd0\xf6\x11\x82y\x13\x9cUb:j\x13\xa72\xccl_J\x90*\xf0\x1b[t\x84\xcb\xad\xff>qg\xf7\xe7\x93L\x04\x8fT\x91\xfe\xc9\xd1\x84]\x9f\xcd\xa6\x9e3W[\xbb\xcb/A\xbbZr\x9fq\xf5Wj\xe4\xe0\\\xadt)\xea\xee\xa7]\x80A1\x04\x8e\x9aM\x00', format=lzma.FORMAT_RAW, filters=[{'id': lzma.FILTER_LZMA2}]))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NVJda9tAEIQ-5lf4zXFJGn3Gp5CUqpBAg52CcBHY55o76a61Y9mOpFC5ob-kFPLS_qj-ms740gfdjlYzu7Or-_lnt2-_bjfPz78fW3sq_r76tax227rtrb9X6sh0pjgmelOaYlvtatM0x7ovO-PJzvOueaRznpHsEn37RXZaZJeN7EoFCJKJEQ1igpyRLbiB7EQJekk8yvGmv-EYys6G1f3Gl10BUUnBuRMWCTrZgNkQD5geWAmZwc04Ypcmd3SlMnwdrpADTYEuaDXWKFBMUcszm5g6mnZ1DtE7c8ANBtU54_4wW-DMCgEdR_GD-88oZ5fImTsgFBHh6hQoltJpaZ_FNbBWGxzx4j30-h0KmCktPaJscaI4Nvg-1XukKIYBi-izcICkH5L7SV-sHFZDeCqK9eIWee812FD4eob1iohdQClp8e0Dfokdum0k4Qh98V3YiVufNVyu6y4iDJtYJKBU6J6YMJ_BuGbBs5RoWpPyQKs5VxwdFibZrR0AKw5He3PuPfVf2iGVqDFX2T_p2W1dqfbqcKtuPmbjdLLI0hz55bo1dXM1e-ovy_5FzxE-jCbX2WI0HafBj_lg4G7py2X9f2n_AQ)

IDKY I brute-forced

Comment: I guess I should have made n larger to avoid brute-force

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269257/76323), 873 bytes

```python
import lzma;exec(lzma.decompress(b'\xe0\x00\x86\x00\x7f]\x00\x05\t\x8c\x1f48\x17VAca7\xfc\xaf\xf6\xcd(?\xfa\x11\xf2f\x12\xa8\xe8\xd5\xeb!\x99\xe1\xe7\x81i\x94\x9ej\xf1\x95\x1f\xdd\x83\x11\x01\x84\xb8\xa9=\xe2\xa6\xe6\x88\x8b\xb0\x8a\xacWkV\xc4!\xb4\xaf\\c\xfa\xbc\xf9\xb1\xee\x04\'\xe7d0pJ3B\x02\xcbH\xa2u\r6\xe2>4\xb8\x8f\xe1\x99\x1bW\x8c\x0cT/\xd7wt.{_\x89\t\xb1Ws\xdc\x7f.\xcc\xd6\xb8\x0f\x874\x8eH\xb4\xccq\xb7UV\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00b\x00\x01\x00\x18a85aa25882b90aaa356ebd56b\x00\x01\x00\x008\x00\x01\x00\x006\x00\x01\x00\x007\x00\x01\x00\ndf940ede04a\x00\x01\x00\x000\x00\xe0\x00T\x00A]\x002\r\x88&\x926K\xd9\xf0vNM\xc8\xee\x93\xdfB\xf5\xf5t\x85\x88:\xf9\xa5\xe0\xeb`\xc4\xbdK\xf6s%\xe4\xdf\xae\x1a\xe1-\t\x91\xda\xab\xd0\x10\xea\xa1\x9d\xcd\xec\xe9\x95hD\xb8\xfb\x90\x8e\xe8\x9d\x99"\x14\x00\x00', format=lzma.FORMAT_RAW, filters=[{"id": lzma.FILTER_LZMA2}]).decode())
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVPbbtNAEH3gR0IkaCLRsHa89m5RQEGACm1AikIiwVZhr6qhaYLtgqHiS3jpC3wUX8OZbPrQPIx3fHbmzOzZ2d9_Nz-a8_Xlzc2fqyYcin_3ynK1WVdN5-LnSj_xrbc98gbO2_VqU_m67pkD1XqmWgYTeVyLcBYdxlUD2Ko2CZnAt5iPrS5UGwDpgBUZ1vWewdPYTrCmgJMU24j3MMexmvuqlRIOIjzyRVICyGD-M3KASk5FEO6wO4xcDCYQZECj5QipxIuSHiYACoNNahzFtV18maObDKVMtm1P2diXoRXVDVX34M0UnbpwbPNm-Bz_oLXmGDnplaqIP326KytCbJqaT8wiisHs7DE6Lb43g-slIEkqmWRRA7Qk3wB8cFweSRhIRAFG4Y9jc9Z-hVO8n-90ZvGw0Td3gURowbVOuRCpkUxrPeS5N47nZj9T7AP5PlDcAS5dkBnzzrNM70fu2oqzMaPPeDsVqapI_IfQJM1PcEgoE9i3txOcSkR9Je7PBQgbOBmNEKeco3gNmkdabz7RfUEId0KjVD8AllEqYkCTaNL-kMSVaMvRJePIjjShdPqnq3E0g_iH4l7SJJ2_iLoHREsaDx9HkSKl7CI9uz3lwaNOWFcr3Yy2D-PVu-lkPFtOxwvg5UXjq3r08bpbuu5RJwa8Pp29nC5PP0zG6a-z_vYlOd_r9-OL2z282wf4Hw)

[Actually even the part you don't specify can change](https://tio.run/##rVPvb9MwEP3c/hVeJWijleGkSeNUBCiCabAOpKqsEk017NhhoT9JA2RM/O3lXVw@rOIjH2xf3t29Oz9ftnfl7Wbd2@/z1XZTlGz5ayWbzVGs2klleFJxLNG3Z5jNrcGDpAScJpWb@QJ7eD1MZZhUGSCZ4URGqjsvYEm4XZweYNeDG/EGSwc41UlSRREMRBjkCzcH4GOZr8gBGgVUBOEa3p7l4lgCQQo0MoqRSrwoabAEQKHgpMZRXKbTxTW68VFK@XV7SWr7UnSiuqLqBrx@QrcONd@@673CN2hTdYEc73tSEL/3/FBWZLZpat5VUysGTydP0Wn4szy7vwEUkUrKne4ApiTfGfhg6L4l4SARIRiFubDNpek3GOHH64PO3F7W2v5DwBVSBFJ6gRCeiriUshf0jdJBXx1npsdA/xgIHgBrnUU@N9pwXx5H9qxhZ2NC27CeCi8pSPzH0MTrX@KSUCbjP95f4VbC6hshV2cQNgto0QgFlDOwzyADS2vUZ3ovCKEvaZR2j4D5lIoY0LiStH9C4kZoS9Mj48qaNKF0@qan0TSD@MbtTUSTdPva6p4hOqLxMHYUKTKKWkj/KzFvN5Vicf03nGmTblbbwux2nVGXZZtiJcu49px/GF8NJzfj4RR4vixNsYtn961ctwY29fztaPJmfDP6dDX0fs@dmkqbjtPcFvm6ZB2lnCYIWc7yNSvk@ovpLM26M3KcQbPRKIs7OhrlvzqZ8UE@P1Xtl@3T0Sw/dQfz/9UbKuYZK9lJzJSqG2joCi3MZouuUrPFvFtim1M1tnjYOO7jMCTXYSdxHVcTACO/rhz2jAWWtHEQoeyyvMvgAmqq1GzL2t9q7fd/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), generate bunch of solutions for [Command Master's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269216/76323)

```python
import sys
s = '77925340277363824169293758807642437284508406489944233814731817114744334387054677199464359370358303681225801571736917189241020964424020531423054738521455432784731931386377196234255749859141710848221995*7660297729448052594468076976871308901099050010752258215140275334247136696601489292003583235840730794856813394396865245853772202539436917905108732823263342134564638227230398268672502337581353160403575356676232895580244410109024495577929416391%997624712161309143295415334518642567808466476564516128021383833912794511198191262082650250977292178811713461440089160581066992373718706289075971369001597094521060013695658387955211810675571614035311614'
g = '0123456789+-*/&|^%~'
for i2 in range(len(s)):
	for c2 in g:
		sys.stderr.write (str(i2)+','+str( c2)+'\r')
		for i1 in range(i2):
			for c1 in g:
				try:
					cmd = s[:i1] + c1 + s[i1+1:i2] + c2 + s[i2+1:]
					if cmd.count('**') == 0:
						t = eval(s[:i1] + c1 + s[i1+1:i2] + c2 + s[i2+1:])
						if t == 2:
							print(i1, c1, i2, c2)
				except:
					0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZLbbhNBEESf7a/Yl@Aroa/TPZHyJRCkyHHCSoltrZdLJMSvmxo7wCuy5O2Z7TldVbOH1/HLfqenU/9y2A9jd3w9To/dbTeLqOJqJBFaNMW4VKkanklRTExD0pzSqFjWaiaqyRbKycEozFRNM8itRDBaiqkDQeqppCVZxJPYgzGj4lRWzCGhWoDDbHJlcEEITRc2d1OJbFOqsmbRRi6iJu5hNb2yAQRZKYKZvoxSSGqEQGKSi@NZmocaJYOVshJTreSEZ3jTJOzcrDsciKGplAoMw6hUobMBwZ9RKEW1dJhRraa1ZHExT4cyEUKG2G3mMACyQiVFpTQwq3mxFq4ETGpNwekQJ0SJoFlhv5BhHJR4KQGjktURmpghKehuFXbadVXckVa@qnDWVAsX2EMgKtWNmxnnxN15iURCpVgUKHD0CZDIEz8QBJacmWsyFkUIwiDK6RyjcGQyQlYrbEYIECohl5BSFQ3FRQYVKEWctaVXES0qAlbQhhX2vCDFDIgX5nY6YANSml/lVsymT@1TJJaWVGRdvV9@ePfz89Wv2fRxP3S9dP2uG@53T9v583Y3Py4WN9NJe7M5v3nCaoIv@vo4PmyH4fr70I/bbn4ch3kvi9VsPVu1Gt1YfBpmC7SfufyPi8ZGuVD5L3UyGYfXSzHZvDxA5vHjTc933ap1rbDqecU3vZx35LIj2Lm7nOkfOxy73uy/7sb5bLmcLbrb247eiJMRwO23@@f5/1IXbwfBHRtJ/pAmh6HHiJ7XQKwR2brZPb/c/thsD@NbI51OvwE)

I don't know which is intended or not listed but a bunch of solution provided. You can also claim xnor solved it

Time: 14m22.162s

Output: [Here](https://tio.run/##bZ05diW7jkX9HIUcyJBWrgz25GS@XWaNoKb@67LD2VeZxnvayYtgA4I9GPG///O///3v8xE/wsfnr@ejrr@v/z7yh62/5eP3r3T@xo/v19/P119bf9PH7/U3v57ff@v6O59rH1/rbz9/x/kbno/vX23DlgzhFbIgXsgTnlcqL3oJRac8f633wXryGG5iL7CV2wUrZKabLsyQ@JxUYnwVaUGaZZvJvehzScd8hW754y3IC3bUcczHXv/6SLcoKR6hF7zUNC6toHSeSyvKWaY0S5JmmdItU7plSrdMaZxs5ucU5QX2a/7vI9/Ic3799gpa5EEvqTylbuS53aj6hTF/epxmRT@35md1zOBJn79m@KH1a7ry@WS0lKOzMtN7JXGozDyUm4dyi1NvcerUXmmX1m/XJGo66q/5PlZOFS2oM1P12lytr8dmJJNeP04db8qXlli7UUx4PW2HVh6uHtq1k3btpN08tPLKeptxthtnuwbX@ol8QXsPGtP2Z3ptptLaDlt0wlaTmaWfD036nGSbZhx91kqfxe638vtVUr@Ntr/S2NH3WbCencqlJdZnXGXTCZpZ3PIzO31mrN@MjfT6cYRX0Li1P65ORj0Qnnjb3lO90bfbtB9vma92/3pi/nvxtMMhPhJXdtXBKz5bfH/Pp@Cbdlhx8s5AvUFYrXgZ/ORXPGGnv4o4Q169kHdM8TaF4H1FiKt9FceVQCy3oLHeLO0OI04rmXwlx40yhftMur3Oph22qnL2GS8uHrqUfEKX6aUsXhJL0SkdvqGrqGkVL3vxcro5yNl73tmI19PZ1Ze7y93GG3bzL494Ub5PF4@xlNsDl9vuQrl9aCjDn5i0ZBbfLv62wuB9QqheGdVNrSb/dRnAavvBe4ZQNWh0f3qVpi5t7mZfK7gdmZPnFu5zzfXWljG8OgjnRW72u3tYPUXwriI0DVerhho5v7E5F4UvWhqccb545Xf1IcE7kfDqI05@V99xYvB@JPSlxf2UdyWhe9n6qtUZ3@VF5Wq8e4PvXp7uNbz7mJ2/w0PcA3jpebhVDm8XY@Vl9TdheBsZS4@jrKF8PTVDnG@4IfyM10/4@L89lj8@9D/ZpwXZ5WYZ578nz9TEV2K2siW3@BN8JZaVndz0Fd9sfTF4blb3F9fcJoZrO5MMoVe23umId2UxXDuOYU1Ewirt6rzSoSMZb51GzWZiW3Oel428eHyMxf85vGXnhGnKbf4E734hJk8h3bYZU3KqPr3ynOYAOs/mWbaYl4bzte@4Zig3tHvo7X/imqWsXJQ7XMQ1Ydlh01qWzOH9e16h8R/80nlJS7q6dPUUbu8di5d9TVViKeD@Dz5lrOHqfdH93XO@erQbGm9q3rvF1bslpx12x5zoU6Lo/V2s1X9dFlwTOP@DXxpYM6G4pkLiHT5l@gqvb2zOV8YgY5A5JVmzqvXvxZ/gK@GW0dYkekr9xVdirUbaai3Ny@79b2x32hHXHGzJ/MU3Ll8g9OdquwcPy2cU23TDjjV0r4vVK65fFn@CTzr9TsJjd7tatP7/WlU8b3zXGstuTmiAhGtreJ82XD/D8zVcE6PfkgxvV0NrmnEsNT13pEjeR6ZnttW0pmHpWbl3PquWx58Pd36f1kovPeQKnpO@tCZ9YnP25ZP3hikUD6unpg6FtJ5Zy6o1R0uhueyaz3ioneeWNkJZz/Xz3OYrcWcoKT6@ugtnETvp89dwmjKT42ED73BD@ClPXK07rPLG5EvJO4OadCXr1WlcZYwBzPDsfCUMEgaJU8roy83outmz1iO5uf6Db96WnuZvr6XuqlnnI5FWLxhXOdPW1uWT4lo/n1KthfP67cWulbWKVuiN@c5aJ92wO/4kH39Sum180onRx6SUd4rjL17z/BnyF5@08l36pux6zLedpTV@TRnnRaulrGVyKktfznefIOi5w3O2drl7@JZeVlQuf4JvfHe9cqj8DL29xSSFSXJz@ge/6qTsfK4ZoPNN2Uu9qZAzuDjf5wwSN7ZlaWu0TGu8FdviubPievHx9NCR3TzEayvhp4wh3DzcrbG6bqtrcVPd@zvvfGVdzz5epzUaJ1GN4PwPvnHN0eSGLt2vkfgnX@llc2t8Tr7RkdqdMx6qq1U273lbUsqb1zgstr/C7x6Wa2XT@f2dT9tf4/cN3Zze2P6SMcgYZMRLZ2sd9ZNvDpvn0EeK5v3FWhel/vyDbcU1eZW8hze2v8IN4SftvlbLPR7@BF@JciRs8ZRI/@Ar7X3PXof1DF6j1drJEdvlNecQn/jGHOXm/yev0jifOvP5RRrLDscaO8dK0fnG5lpds431y4tXjpztbHA@vue58zAtMu8ZibMdieTbomltgt7QT/CVvTOZSZ9O99e5Ospz@2rxfD6v8PrG5txWeFs8PL6xJNobv2L0/e68NrzXb4s/wScnITrNfC6pw5uu3nO4M4K8Zj1L5i@2xTOF5jHM0emG9iVd/8EnF75nntdOV55zmsUntjXTyGumkH3WkdfsQqGnbtdMYz5riz/BV6JDYuUn1n/wzdsaDVbvlH0jPqe74tq01yc5@enGWqfOzc6Fe@vn8/JqCJvzmmr85JN0WruOL@kZyzKYtJMsvqu@5iMlON6MTpb0jW8v878XzWOW34eK00t5Tp@HBsgOTQsR3t@ntQhv6Dz/OJiihyYlOo8gDu4zho1ZqCyUIMzEm7OieIuyU5SdeTAg9NDgj1UVaC1TD0ohryXkl9BDo2u2STtNkTXE0B3nPtrF5DF0la0rhmNQqyqkyVEVqiTC86i2noRw1NcjzYdXjYm7KjIor5M9zoBnX43wC@zyuzEdhvUk5Cch3YS0Xqbw7SyNT5YM4smygZBV3XMT@QuscDxbGmSgw6o6DRXxV8RfKd8hD/006KTh2YZ0YR5zA/MLrHC12bVp6sxnu2QG6nqgcQ60zkcGuLYwnVXeCDtZG4vO0eOc24TfYH82Kj9zq81lSpRMkf2sjbHLVV3H2pC63JBuY3iTfJMNzw0Uj3OdOV2GzEDPOCJY5ZobC95pPQhfGwOXIROUVnrrBqXPuZD0eLLKtZZLzoin4NmKdKt0mKCrOR0XN6VVkf@mNrKnsJdVX3Oa6DKv7kmdN/IwClhpzYmSenjlM8OW1qTEWXmYkwOXiSpLhg7nyOlpvUZNr7t427v9mhvGl3eLulPzTc1pOJ0xtmk820cKKxNNQ1DbZ8CORajHmlJtSqLrsa7HugSGBIYiG8ru7Uw3M7wj9xGMorQMRsE74uyIc0Ajo4CV1jopuRxU6L1HfNQetgE1X29tnhUZ/sq/IS1DPHaqqvvUpO9K@764u561@/kIo@OZj3TNPPqeeXxdVApn5nHwpnYsoGu60bdrwE3iGEPXbKJvu7iZPOPHOs7PHnpmCF0m0mUifR@dX9mhUtyRvmOk39w8RwEKuMbTj/G45pLSv6Pp5qFnz8jaMZp2jKYdxtYxUvZzKOlptYxwyDfEc0bEDuPcnJWfjvhPr9RhqP2MWOYM84iq0nkM5HxG/b2lnyR/Rp1@tp7doALC4@PP3p69n601hQ/Xw9wGc5mCeIrqLp1ZZj89ssfTpau59Hb5IZ5Lz/vsXMqIq2Suvb9WFcJXi0sHW/TQl9n1g@E1AH5ddpOyZVIuU@Jq24trlsyrWQznpnCvtnu6efi1krvy@4Tscv2ol6vyECtkmjiFR/waTPLlV/7/XH6p3hl5vn1WX@vv5GXcyt7n@461OB6rPz45F48Nj93Ab@hsRs5NItP8xc15nh9f@Wnmzmmb8OKsOPeJ5OWueOoDVjH2Odjl4rxPNA4fkx9nd/umNc3fuagsc6Li4U3lSk3lmhMG56CyzF2E@@wcDTL48@pnWdzyidl9@sKxrHksW1qmtLB8xINnVNibK8L08RwseuyFfy42Yf9oB6vy8FLmFXiV9Ya@ht2LvXtqc/nWnKv4pW0vk2vb1rKrXk6QP8vozSrj9LpxmVeN9MsV6VYpYi5txMpyONPsxa9OOjknKPxR3l4ds@dhKJ/TG6F6rQyXiQlVdHqWzUW1@Gp7/mxGPC9rD169j5dx9hSebkX8p6fY3Fy38wzZ5V9N@AG7TJOubi@zuYGlw3kK7PkZqtP0qE7nGanb5Ku3Gs4J4UprLj2684A9Z8V5luGLXy3l6jBl1XvKss59DnQYdp@K7GqehjzOsqXZS7p8x7Mdee4N3CEzFD4GGqTinD3v46yyz/3OW/azS7kZbWRujiVn5WG7ts79yLwXDHnuFec9HTp8w/@D8P/spUR@acIl3jmfuMNHRWg/ofEleyk4RafklJ2KU3VqTop5eHpxeWG/8rLOGZcFHvp9KPivwX@NHhanzg59Odmh5L@mj@L06XTlVi0cummU2X8fqk73ierxrZa7qHmumqfbQfeJ4XLDUxue@@FpBCkmSDPhcdE9X9gYPLsvvPl9DbqPsAnHxaTHkh7Lemy6ujv6Y8WL9cJbrlCJTfgl9LI1xduUhybZrjx0RdaVhy5ZaXQPpRchcBN@jVBJWIQuIIOLQbLRM/nCq6iYJJtknUmmKMuKMq3XyP4Io3AIPYYq2SrZKlmZXZTdxa7QroSHIhuu1OkCJ/TWIe2kx2WTVPJCF4jEJvwSfgq9ecr6kqzvNTsMwi78EnpkMsQkQ0zSWZLOknT26l6L0PPblQfpLMm4kozr1cE@wigcwpvJLEW98KaW1Yll9WJZ2tnTu4tNOIQum5VElqzsLMvOsuwsy85yVXaqsqMWm2VnWXa2HDQOqofLarFZzXQP3Bf9saHHZJNFzbTIEIv6vqIOr6jD21siG9Vii1pskVJLcpUUKbWow3uhxyDjeqFnUjorVQOHdFbUtb2wCj@FLtuVcNdjarFlSEAttqjFVhniC28MVf1Z1Qj6mmRGYRb6ACftVDXTqtGzyuSqTK4WpVaUGoZLjQxVrbA2hn4JPTWppKqZ1qHQwdAv4Y2hyYya@rOmjr/JoposqmkIbdJZ0xDapLOm4aBpOGjqz154rbppVtGkqCZFNUwsZFGvyfsjbMIh9BJrDGjqz5r6s6b5R5ftdNlOl@10dfzLreOgOrGuTqxLJV0Tr65OrGuE7OrEuqYdXRbVNe3oaoVdrbCrE9vT@I1Vpaiu6t6IXeiPSWcdczf1XF0m12VyQ1O1oanakPqG1DfU3oY6ppGIHoNUMtQxDalkaCwcmrEOGddQHzXUrw91TEMqGZpzDfXgQ3OuoW57qGMa6piGOqa5XxDBGawZrtQy2aePT0R4fAvX5BcT1idhfozZ64Pp64P561MwtcZk9pEBhacgnxXxVJSlIQ8NeeiIvyN8IJ6BeDBX5bSf8/63KT7m@CHgWUz4OePnlD@odc5d0gB2PXDaHzLShd5CQd4K8gBdBegqNOQN0//QkDfoLXTkZ7yx2wOm8JMb2PMTg9KK0GFU3zXZ44/pjRV/hnyGDHQSYUuYuU9uYC9vbIi/QaYjHMufCD1E6gGrRkzcA2buIWEljWl8SPGN9SxsI0EnSZ332Vk/rLVOwMQ9YOY@b/ZlsORhMwk2g4l6wEx9HgYlsGTQptLAghZtKmtqOdnzltGmsmZKx9XjMPST0b4ydJXRF2GKPvc9M7iCXYeYsQdM2QPm7JMVZ0U8Feli0Y3Z@mTlvyP@jrxhYY15esBEPWCmPtnly6P8FPRdBX0@puuTJQPdFui2YI@ioM8vsL2C9lgy4oHtFbTTgr6roJ0W2GFBO93eWoehwwKbLOi7Cvr8An0W2GeBfWLqHjB3D5i8T/YyYs4@uYI9n5jBB0zh50kXWc/C9ipsr8L2KnRVucdT32SUB@ztVIyVmOTPffwAdr1V7OpUzVRDg64adNWgqwZdNbTfpvVhwMx@cgMPsJ5FH9gwLjTos0GfDe26YZesFaRVESe2zxp02KC3hjlGgw5bw85ahzz02WCHWASERt1iHOkYRzrGkY4@EwuEgBXCcRFzVpzQeddyKnTovEPnHe29o1/FqmEeuAew8gAb7hh3sF4IHX1ph/47bLujL@2ol445TIedd9QFlhOTlX/MA7GiCFhHTE5gT3cE6XBgbvPiAf4Ce34G@tgBmx8JcaLfGAlxQucDeh7obwfmP6O8hX@CFQ/624Fxf0DPo0EnGMsG7H9AzwNzg9HfZBQn@t4h@5@eQgVcwdpA1hxy8gB/O@Nc4omIPyEcO8ZYp0yu4E@w8lCQh4J4sHGM9UvE@mWy4tecfHIGD7Dy0CHfId8h35HugAz1PJBP7dHM2@IRXMHan@cGfYBMgAxOiAL267Hemex1jfXOOfc9jO35oH47Yl0Tg@ZdEYcdEWucyQ2sfHbIdKTboZOBPMtupythADP8E@xpvZ1m4Cwtqq84TkeHocOofmPero/gClY8WoNPzuABVloFeYM988gjwm4j7DbCbiPsNnbEiTOQ2JFP6BbrqXnT/wFnsMePNdTkBvZypYh4oMMUEQ/0iWOQiHVWxDor4nxksuKErWJtFbG2mqxwnBZhbTV9FyK4gpWfARnYZBpvMq4HnJFM1plYQHh4C9cRWoSMxqyYobcMvWW05Zzfwl2HGfaW0a4zdIW11fTbeMAZPMCKHzrEYch05MtgHQjCxrBuijjwmO99iGCPs6CdYg0VsW6arDg1dk9uYK@vwmNJ6KdUPFsRjkNInHREHGpMVjj0UKCHinaHddBk13OFHir0UNHWKvRQ0dZwwDE98h5wAQ/wJ1jPog1iDTX9dTJY5aqQh11V2BXWSpOVB/RjFbZUcZhb0XdVHOdWtMGGk@8GG2uwsYaxA2uoyR0sebTNhnEWa6WIo5DJehZ22HA43mB7OCU5PkyHYYc4KJm@TQFcwZ9g6QTH5E37SMcv6jD6uoa@rqGvw5nJ8aM6DFvt6N863Ak65ocdfRrWPvOdGhGscHgS4HRk8gB7eTv6N6xx1ts6nKHD3hAn5n69v4UP8CdYcaK9d7T3gfY@MPceaO8D9jkwn8HaZ7K8GdAfYr0zWfFgHoiTl4hDlskM17PQOc5cJg@w8gkPjlGRH/hwDMwVcSATscaJAzaMk5rJGaw4YbdY70x/vgBWeEA4fDsetfHJ7i2BtUzCWma/90Tszh4P/DqejPjhw/EUxF/wLDw6nopn4dPxVMg3yMPZA@uaye5R8nSUEW4gT4cMHEEe6DPIhicXsKcVZKsJa5aENct880sCd/AXWPKy4YS1TAoJ8hlxwpkmwJsGa5yENU7CGidhjZOwxpnXyQJY5YI@4b6VsJZJOMeZXtoRLA8i7XVMLuABdp3ECHn1sSlGyNMXKUEe3kgxQT4jHDqM0GGES1IskC@QhysS1jIJ65fJHaz4oU@cByWsZfbbZy4PlIt6HijXgCMW9J/QJ@DMaLLCoWc6f2Fdk@jzhfOjyR3s@U8ZechIC/1Dgn3SywtnRol@XqkhTtgn1jiJbl9Y4ySscSY3sOsNZ0nHX/kw2jvWNQlOXwlnSQluXwl@X5MzeIAlnyGPfjVnyGfIwz4z7BPOYPsdPGI9W5F/9MNYE01WnB1565DvyBvsFuujhPVRwhlTytA/3MQS1k0J503zEtMDLmDPQ4E9Yw11/MsPo7/FOVTCOVQqqBe4j6WCfgNnUvNSVQK7/eBManIBD7DiQT@M9VeCq1nCWiwV9CEF@i8D@YH@K@YMFf0DzqQSvMsmf4FdJ1ijJazREtZo8wpxAEsG@qzQZ4U@sf5KWH/t9wJdpnco@g2cYSWsxSZ3sMoC266w7QrbruhD4KE27yE84AIeYE@roT@Bc9q8fBfAigf9BtZfCeuvhPVXwvor4dzqXL0@XJAWnG2xFpvcwUoL87EG3cJxbV7tzuAOVh6gz4Y@Ge5rkyvY89C1bz@5gyUD@@zQJ86n5luIHnABU8bzDLe2yRk8wJLHfAxubqmj78VZ1byvksCSh31ivZawXks4h5rcwK4TrNES1mgJa7SEdVmCq1vCuiwNzG8H5rc4b0pYi6WB9QLWYvNKfwQrHO0a66yEdVYasEmsuSY3sMoCHWKdlbDOSlhnTXbH54cu4tLbuS/k7N7RT4AfOfzEcZaUcZaU4QuXsRbLWIutN0Q5Z@RHdpjhF5dx3pSxLss4Y8o4Y8rwhTv3nZwp477eWJdlrMsy1mUZ50oZvnMZa7GMtdhkudfDFx/nRxnrr8kN7HkLETIRMtAz1lwZa66M86OM86NzO/SwxqYM37kcCmTghR8q4oHzPdZZGWdJGb5zGWdJGb5zk3X/ALrC@VGG71zGWVLG@dFkxQO94W7MZMWTIJMgA73hrkzG2irjnChjbZWxtsq4MDNfyRHAihM6jO0tXPF35Ac6jLivEAdkoE@soTL87uYbJB5wBusmR4RMhEyEDHSIc6L5epEMdp3gPCjjPGiy6ypBVzgburfz8rm9nMAqV0c42mmCrtJAudBOk9ahmfdncDY07yImsKeb1dfdWan5fUHz@4KT/hy6Paj53UDzG4Hm9wDNb/@Z3/kzv99nfqvP/C6f@V0@0229hTdl3@wxXcYz3cAzXbsz3bUz3aozXaUz3ZQzXY8z3Ykz3X4zXXkz3XMz3XMzXW4z3Wgz3WgzXVgz3VIzXU0z3Ucz3Twz3TwzXTcz3TEz3TEzXSwz3SYzXSFb@Efoj0lnfhhqugBmuvVlut9lutRlusllur5lurNluqhlup218GbHV@mmK1kLXSArhqxQaTJLk37jynS3aqE/1hXZcCyqWD8oNF2HMl2HMt2BMl18Ml1xMt1rMt1rMl1mMt1gMt1gMt1VMl1QWvhHeGX9RM90K8l0/8h0/8h06ch0vch0vch0kch0e8h0Zch0T8h0Och0I8h0Dch0Dch098d04cd0tcd0icd0c2fhLXFDlyH1@RLIdF3HdF3HdF3HdEfHdBvHdAXHdNnGdK3GdIHGdGvGdFXGdD/GdCnGdBPGdOfFdLvFdLvFdI/FdHnFdGNl4dXDUH/m11RMd1NMF1JMt1BMt1BMV09Ml0wMt0kMt0YMN0UMN0UMt0MMN0IMNz8MNz8MNz8Mtz0MNzwMNzwMNzkMtzc2axzAQMCRgENBkPnrNobhBsZmxVmQFvLpnkebJd8R55CuohqCbkgYbkUYbkIYbj8YbjwYbjwYbjkYbjYYbjMYbjAYbioYbids9vwn1G@Cftw7xnDzwHDzwHDbwHDDwHCrwHCTwHB7wHBjwHAzwHAzwHAbwHAbwODpb/D0N3j3Gzz3DZ77Bm99g4e@wfve4GVv8KY3eNAbvOYNXvMGT3mDp7zBU97gEW/wgjd4vhs83w1e7QZPdoP3usFj3eCxbvBSN3imG7zRDR7oBq9zg9e5wdPc4F1u8Cg3eI4bvMUNHuIGD3GDV7jB@9vg8W3w@DZ4eRs8uw2e3QZvboM3t8Fr2@C1bfDaNnhqG7yzDV7YBi9sgxe2wfPa4G1t8LA2eFIbvKcNHtMGL2mDB7TB69ng3WzwaDZ4Lhu8lQ3eygYPZYNXssET2eB9bPA4NngcGzyLDZ7FBm9ig9ewwVPY4B1s8A42eAQbPIINnr8Gb1@DV6/Bq9fg1Wvw5DV48ho8eQ3euwaPXYM3rsED1@B1a/CoNXjUGjxqDV60Bi9ag7eswUPW4CFr8IQ1eMIaPGENXq4GL1eDl6vBs9XgzWrwYDV4qhq8Uw0eqQbPU4OHqcGT1OA9avAYNXiJGjxDDd6gm32FmbRgiBiz5A1q8AY1eIAavD4NHp0GL06D56bBW9PgoWnwxDR4WRo8Kw3elAavSYOnpMFT0uAdafCINHhBGjwfDZ6PBg9Hg1ejwZPR4LFo8FI0eCYaPBMNnokGD0SDB6LB09DgXWjwKDR4ERo8Bw3egpv/gD0PNUE@QV5jq7wFDd6CBq9Ag1egwfvP4OVn8PIzePYZPPsMnn0Gbz6DN5/Bm8/gwWfw2jN47Rk89QyeegaPPINHnsELz@CFZ/C8M3jYGTzsDF51Bu85g8ecwUvO4Bln8IYzeMMZPOAMHnAGDziD15vB083g6WbwbjN4txm82wwebQaPNoMXm8FzzeC5ZvBQM3ilGbzPDF5mBm8ygweZwWvM4Clm8A7b7PY8pHN5hBk8vwyeXwZvL4NXl8GTy@C9ZfDYMnhpGby0DF5aBs@szb7r83TksyN8IM/abZA3lsEDy@B1ZfC0MnhXbf4D9nxi7JNHlcFzarOe1TgoDymDV5TB@8ng/WTweDJ4ORm8nAyeTQavJYN3ksHzyOBttFk7ag0y0HlEPqNsPmE/L2FDT55EBu8hg/eQwWPI4CVk8BIyeAkZPIMM3kAGDyCD14/Bu8fg0WPw4jF47hi8dQweOgavHIP3jcHLxuBZY/CsMXjTGLxpDJ4yBu8Yg3eMwSPG4BFj8IIxeMEYPF8MHi4GrxaDV4vBk8XgyWLwTDF4phi8UQzeKAYPFIPXicHTxOBpYvAuMXiXGDxKDF4kBs8Rg@eIwXPE4C1i8BAxeIUYvEIMniAGTxCD94fBy8Pg5WHw8jB4dhi8OQzeHAYPDoOnhsE7w@CRYfDIMHhkGLwwDN4WBm8Lg4eFwavC4D1h8JgweEYYPCAMHhAGDwiD14PB68Hg6WDwdDB4Nxi8GAzeCgYPBYOHgsErweCVYPA@MHgcGDwLDJ4FBg8CgweBwVPA4Clg8A4weAQYvAAMJ/@G037DCb/hVN9wkm84vTec2BtO7A2n9IaTecNpvOE03nDSbjhdN5yuG07UDafohtNywwm54YTccBJuOOU2nGwbTrYNp9mGE2zDqbXhdNpwCm04eTacKhtOkg0nxoZTYsPJsOE02HAabDgNNpwAG053DSe6hlNcw2mt4VTWcPpqOHE1nLIaTlYNp6mGE1TDCarh1NRwamo4KTWcjhpORA0novdtsferx5POhyQW7fFDH2va2Dx0v2x94TlQKnpfXfFvB2ysirYrsmPjBW82KXpl/@aC8DKQEcg0hJ8@puAmfMGt8oJbxAU3MMu58ejhyEMsQdwecBSfOXs5NyJu@HnD8eYYwcrD9aAt8HAt8BYt8M4s/mXGww0yXTI5RTDCz35z8bfblnVafcnr2lTBpgo2VbCpgk21aqhVQ60aatVQk4aaNNSkocYMtWSoDUMNGGrAUAOGGjBo3aBpg6YN2jVo16Bdg0YNGp2807pfV510vkCX9cGtjdnxlrQeu/sC3/B7w6WeGxnOVfGcT6Ydrn@nakjKkJQhSkOUs0A7mvkBw7FHnnbu7X9eDlF8ctD8q9eHG7jr2av35l/1vJydb0kW5/KPdA3xG@I3xGl49vZ880t6V8cdKe2vqPyLZyw79vVV@efy/drw5hvPOM/a4XNesL5ne/bNNu/cLz7Pbt5pne/fLgz@ttj9bdtntYvNu2oXH91s8RNjkP7eeH4XXuxvCJ9ff/@V9yfHfvDRX1lflDxPpvvNxf1F@VGcb3zk/T7ZtWrevDU8vdRdZlnx3s37wedLiKVBGtZx@F/hhnC3iNIRz/0Wby6oycU31BtRRX1tXl/X3bx0UYN0O9cqLg39by5rtfmDPbc16o3uNXrs0P/mI5FcIiP9vKSrOF2@0gWhBWXzb1bWhhSh/fU93bw/EFT9K5rzc3JbaxWta3N9Z/uLvXbmC1r92VUn223D2f7iY5/tfpE8@zd8N53YNud/8Y0heAxoSZvrquvDw3lLR0hH1bV/NXjSTQM1t74TnPd3GX7wlfZvtPrXgzfdGPZ7llfL@sGu0VZkFa2oxTf/YulcKzopbreD@fUXjwF20NDa1neCb/iq2@3f0mAL/ZH8D/bcdrSh7t8t7WhNHa1pfmLwSERIoA7mZyrBnseO/ql7m@hoE70glnf2eXtf@toe@t311dFuOvS1vj6c9xeyOsa63v3JgSfv99lzR99EHtDhgN6G621Ab2PprS/b3bztf0BzA5a8vnJ8Y0yQTxqr3sJ373PZNT3267vjP/hYuX85eZLSh87n5/lOiaDPAfsbsL/h@hyuw0G9DTz3ztcOy3N7k0n3yc03VLLSclnfZV6xgu0vthNLxJOy2p98pe/XnTfd5xJkk@cvu2xG/jNk91vTw8rRe/hNryCVAom9CEzOW3rOgq9ExZPrk7Zrv0Jsf7G5fENKGts333go072mOkra3yT0ZPf8dqQ5lkRdednc/hFuCD86mp/cuOkEt5lwR6BNJ5XFJ4bD/R/hhnDPYbijTQmwmQA7Wbye@StcsSTPl@YKk2@@YSsBNuFf2550Sw7rCLCO4Baxvsd9Q6unUZFGxXPVn2vLkurhY8eh4bllC@t2xOYrYQi9@XT7CLCPAPv4wfe54SkPj2EghjtLLPGRJqL65M0rxr/4zvVKRN8RA57VPH3yb5fZtbz6kXjnFyV6DcbsuUJdRtRl3J89CP8IN4S7zUTUbaxnZJmkfK@WvHbcNt9wtNIffHQcoc84vDTeupK3qIR2lKDjH@y5ThHy6CF/sOTdwlPBk6unW6vczVfi5q@qZhJsOWnGNFkyy25T@QcrJ6u3SqvP@cE@4syv1YEVv9tkRr@UYZ8Zepwfpz7S6FMy@o7FZZ2NHc6Ps2Q879nHn5yR/uSy/N8n/3Fp13kukL6zgZJRE3u3caZ7eEugh8mwyLy/s74s8ge7DnODPKwzN6TUPKXua7KC3YOSB55co8U/@djL3FjbGi@okwIbfmP0DVjDl6LZVSlowaUgHK32tYb@Bp8WjNV3KbBdrLML1tOlwOYKbK4MjdEFM6j6@Hzw8g0/OajQga@iy/y4vctCA9WtFavf4qvfUn3GU703rOgDfeVbsPItWPmWCi0sXrE7Lwv6EX7qtWLEwkq5@Oq41I5QjDdYK5cKW/J1bWn6vltprqUGzfhKtDSMGg1teq1EV5yHr7TXFtalpaGPbBnhrsEG29lrxiyez9tffEvTbt00jOdYSb6Hr/6v/YtvfD42N4wli6/s5vaPcEO4awJrzdJds93n7FhpFqw0J3s/2N0qO@ZZHbrsPk53WCDWme/hS5dr5fiTb67abVVYcZYOvXa3xQ6bW7zi@Yu9NAN9zxtHtfAByxtRreFwF6cb7nkYrq2BUWNAWwO93HArHFhxDFjkWBoaq73@YJXJtbFWjumQUu@@f3Y4XT71hhXl5rLOhTfPmKuvISvWkJvL@lzKT742WLEurE/EswWs3qo@Fc82PNs8L93z0hFHRxzq3yf/dpn1WeC1OvnJ2/ZqUO9eg/r0Gm5vVcPjssF1vPmGep7eOHoMCc8lr5vD6fKVzgiV7dSgeW31dUoN99Rm0/0d@l28nj68n2vIU/OyNOS/IQ6vC1@RVKxIKlYhm@v6JuJPvnpEDYWBJ8FYl1SsS2oMenatOdZThyVjCD@pRu1MV199TLq/J/yeEJvXTNRM7/CRhmVHjSib95N3JVgjNIx1xeYZk/2QgWY3r7ONzSuFwzud4ekM5PWOMxVrluprlpo0SlesSS5357rui//ko78E20@ojfm5xF/rkKxiYbM5HPIOIO0tzw6@4V7taxm0kviLz6FwxTro8IlmnfCvTzX@5H33YcpUf9v04RNPPW9XupwRPnu635dfmvm@MuvrupOvltDuFq9LcDXtI8mPdDCFFUW7Z2gHuwss/@yD02V04/Lo2Thv6f2@nIqLzFtQnmDsHvc@Dz28bjsdrlXhTXmZHs1ixbNPFw@nIs7gApl17nl4IHxMz7WrAoXvd0AcjtBNHOJUwU3cEE@fNyE2z7XCVeyeYR2eO/CXR9azpyx9fnfYOYIzuIL7r3HofH3t4NZ3398tu6FhXcw53IrCO3hUsGKM6yOkl7PC1@cUNk8nz3D4qqy/FW@zXd5dz@HuWc7rszCHq/Kf1@3izWvL9HIO4prETTJrKL28LleeMvqz93Bz8z5GrthoqNNFFpzAFdxOwxxnKjXpC7@/eJVinI8ib1q@YQfrkVwfuA3CK/vqz38fTI8LnHY99tdGm/DrYneBmhzXq3cPllUFY38Zb9zsrI8ZHF4fMDu83JYv12Xw43yA6tO5q1hJ6Yf1grxb8gwtZMVftqWM82EhcfMch9PYh3/I5zLy0KDaVhTeAzirjMsl8zLiGY@r/VrKQIsZaDHDPz5xmeFD4UF5iKz3KD3vl/IfXu7el7PkU3P9z6tOw3l4nuNy5b4cXJ9xuWlfI4uKpwfXSVzurpdRliFL2y@9vaw6Sutq3eEQVg80jkvYl7NsIMXuediu7mKXz8pPyqqL/cLBy1lpFdVFKl3xVOl8uzAfbmpMaV3TuTxUri7950etM68X717unp8cH4XHoPDlSnk5eH3dHnS469pltYu8XMgPr5e/X1bbzOsFgpeT6yGvl6HfXiJ7Hc3D8OQ8xMst@rLqcR7iehczZAPzSPLmpzzKwzwm8/D1EcTDUfGXdXX@snRe0N@VlL0sa/P58nKWuSz9TPZ0m9ry3JYhfznLDktXG5wD9023BtlbjepDakIfn2Qba@Lm/N5Pbjb0LYa@ZV9vfQ7PKxo3fNr25e1Ac7jeOjIfIReX2x7nS0du729rWZUue9589Jtf8v5Vdz7nu2AQnhCeEV7AFdx/zQuGdW2/Px//d2g6Ml/6PpRdbrr6XgpO8dD6/ufBNZHduDqnjcMF1tsXDjaPf73dauN6ge/B6Ems1/EeVMLLvfjgMvGN2ZPYnevG6jlfbzLYuF5G4Pj7YvY8rJskB8fR4BrBbxJ1tZWL30KXLcIq7J7fqnibsrMcTA9KqU2lWPcqDjbPTlO869NojldRXbW6bhwe7F6Kdc/9oPI7hkc23xLilbzeAHK5yw6iNB@W17vYnKtnZb5lQzaUlFbKkl/f5bzcPWthnQRdluLD8vO7jPzsKczmqtLuNzVc7m4Cocr89xsWLmfleXfbzp6HPXQ7B@cEmQpuiv/F384dzw7lbQS0MqSLqttvELg81OgeNfX5FoDoXDzOM13avM56D0e1lv0dpcNos3O65DIJcSblLWbZxv6ujVgyzeto39C@rCayb2VfHipXRcdWo@KpSflBC43rE@6XZfNxfc/xckDHhTiXn9nhjnx29YRn@rZ53Rq6nMBV6Y7hOpw3YL0TfNRG0h6anCWjnjIF9KXr3YyXu54N3fWWouwqrdetiZOz2lpat1Yu9zfO3ocH9fLrPeqXNSZM9nJl2eR@H7jY0y1qU2f6eVj9zL7dd7hCD@ik5407Ly@66XnLroBv2zxT1MNBeWhR@Wyq0zmNdb016KerXzpT2sPQyZ4m7KHrkc3Mm1e/naWfvN4AdXlAfritZozZkxUeNPyv7ztcVj98ptLn/F79QEa7nvd8EtjjRN3lXN/Y48/If26KP3fIq12cjYzDQeXF4J73HtVhtZ3J32DJZDxbNIuYJ9hgyTeEN4Qjz3v6fxjPVsjPM1awwjHVaSgLbCw36ByDf@6Ip6NOe4ZMhgzqqCNvHbbUNWk5yw5nhcM@MTZN38MEvuHTkzGCC9inY0@EjNra9gG8nCGTEV7Bsqvt73ZZ9VXCA@ZEUfU4fbwe5/rGAax4kFZgWtDD@oaIWOEoS6yuwxLVXkpEuRLynyIYukqIM5U3Np8NI56svq6sd5@Kf4O/wHoWecAkvWCWXtBXFPQV0/9F@dGcpKBdl6JxqhSNuaV0hHeEazGzfDqcI6b/0FVVeylovwXzhLLeciL2PGM6v7wanDUdL5hDns3Tw@pbtpfAZZSraU64fAsud5SrIw8dNoy2X/b2m/M32MvStfIo6B/mMt1tAPOZdarunPXsQLqjqCyjIh7EP9Be1jvMxTfOdUbtrGcrxrWzGX1Y87d1PuusuWhFO53nkBHs4fFxG67xQThWfxHLP6x4a0T8UX1sjVxwIs9oyxXttCbkOansd5E/3ytcDoU73O4XEA7nq9b70rvDvqS5LxU7XLKHp6DwOV248cyLzjfZdbnocm/O6poN3bGtLq9fLlnyPuxph@TVMYETuPhU4zWIIrzvs4LZXe2zggyXgMV7QAquxO2Ek5yq0zgU/dc9ydj07fR5aJdrUvFYqsfS/New53sHi/BbeOM8Y9TCPTQebEJ/LCu0KomqJJpi2GPKvuun0g@PLCqT8XGBvaO4MRKb8MYbk6cWk5SZFborP@yzmCj8Fl49xD32HvTImkJVttiUna5Mrk3qjSpxHJ6HvRN68cqm4PGetU7Ye1dReFNLRfYhE0iqi6S6SE2hTaHKTn484SzTyMEfy8Efy9GznmUlWdWSZSX7SPHizeRZix28@j27amEfe0VhEbpAV@jwhIvUVwJDb8UWZb0ov0X5PTsCC6Xq9b2jg7KoogLtc6@NRY9VN8/SvJhFjWFvb28cxCS82anqSurjSVRVVlVl1eipVfUiVZ3H2XMMe0sReEtRld/alMRQEkPxKpNNPVqLLnD62rDvjnfht/CqpBXJFsmqmbbmddHUyFpXHtSttOHxdnUrXZk8m2sHozALb7w9ue10GW1XV9GrHqteQ11NrzfP75n1hL1z6gnLCIb6h7N6P1iEVztDpRhRoeoRh0x5yJRHVrzZszPUOQ6VYqhBjsbQq@r1DuuDw/U7hodO74Vv8JdzAGv0m1zB5pwwoKln3K@5Fmewj29PhXxDuh3hHaNkxziqfiZwJA2qnhDCW7g/G1RDgWNoQP73WdRhGVgIaqCTFd6Qn45nO8bzgTygLuIjfcaAcOgfI2qIGRMDDTZhn3MfVksIEXqO6sDna7F9IhDVg4SESUqCbjEe7tdiX4beUnoL72DXAwbIkNRBh32edxhzpoQJS4KdJOg5dcQDnSeZf8jqtPfrssUVrDmV2uF8dbaXK6trCT4T/Vyvzva6y8hb7ipXxowrq0MMGCEnexkLbAAjY8DQOF@v/YAH@Bv8G6z4NRGbPiKSx9QRI2coDTINz3bp8yzEL2dwA3seKuytos1WzHorbAyj6GS3k6rpTagZz3JyjH6pok5rUVlqQ35ghxiG54HSF9jroqJ@K2yvoq6bZgyhaTo0D6M6WPKa2kxuYM9D00ARGsqFsfqu@sJ57dEDVvztjSXfIY/6bZq1zleCi9EPd9h2R7/RYc8ddtthqx39Rs@IE3ro6Pc6ytjR73X0LR19Ncb70DHWdIw1HXY7HoWPR3keQWUZmteGgXFzJKy2UEbMAsJAuxvI84BNjvHG3RdoWjYcd9nDQUulJ0IGa7cnaon0JMhnz89@bfjlgjViwSJRfft8bXgCZ7DSapBX@zo@XocH0hrIj9rUfLW4pxWwfg@ql@MfdhjLUozpMagtHB@yw1hjYgE9Xyfu@QnIJxfObytnzbti1LxrHsBGsNdplC1FzAf2K8fFDdzBSivj2YxwLK5jRTiW13EgbwNpqe3P15J7ukntfR4gK1x9@OQBVjywse0Y7ezlTRUbDQ1xYvGfusqSsZ@R1fdOv70MLmA9i/aS8xtrWwP2n@sbu/1kzVvm68o9/xntt8BmCvRZAsJh25gD3APzy9pcySp7gQ1gjXx3/TZXxFMRD@wBY/1@7fll2D@Wzcdh3XmAXc9YUM/XpLt@akQ4@ivMByLmA5O/wdpDgh6w3o5VY@tkz1vVcnfyF/gT7PqpsMmKeq/oNzB/2K9bv6y50HHiP4w@AXOD2FDvGNMjxvTYUI8N9dgaZND3YqyP21fPuYIH@DeYzyot2AD2ASZ7eTv6w46yYy4RO/rAjq1HzAci5gMR84GIbYDJnv@OPPcBGdgnxvfJ2kIMYNjngH0eJ53LntbQPGpyAXt5B/coNcZdh5HLw1l7TftV6pcjwiN2OCM2PjUnSY/WBfMV65IvSFf63K9YF3@DP5074pEtJYzdKWh8TAFlDNyKRRmDxpf9yvTLCTIJcWoOM1nxa3yZ3MCe/4ByYT6QMNaniN3jGN44g/3ZiHqJETLYWY44b8CYPlnxoCwY068jz@aCtDROJeykJ4z1KapPmPwN9rrAznrC1vp8KWYAZ3ADe96S5qv7Fe5ijzOh3pPGwZQC5DVepJQQZ35jyaOuk/Z2Jn@Dlc@K@CsOAhry0yEzcEIw3sI9TuxFTPa6xpwkZZQrw2awuT@ZMoof7TprrpWwvzHZy5Iz4tfcYL9q/jJsCXOelKErzH8S9kP2a@fFOitBuygR4emNJQObL9qoTpjDTGex3@AvMGW8XJjzpKL55GSFw85LRzwa1xLOB1LB4RL2NxL2Nyb7s9jrmPwb7HFW1GlFX429jsm/wXoWdYc9kMm/wZKvOMSC/WNuk7A3Mu97RLDKCD002HyDze/7A84ef4PN4wAjtQR52AYOLvar7C9XpKu157mL4lzBv8GKR3sCCXsgkzPY22bHuNDRj@HII@FII@FMI3W0x4767ShXx/jVcejY0Y9hP2S/Ev9yQ5woL45CEuY/02nxASew5NH3DvQzONpIA@ekA/3wQD88kP8BO8Sxx3w9vtfFgP6H5pYZ@x779fjiT7BOXTX/v86YwT9Qf1ntKD84LX0K0pWeM@ZF@yPz9wBX413GfkXGHsX@UPxl5CHgwDZUyGj9O9lPZ4PmYBlnEzl0nC1rzMo4m5jOoR3McM9PlD3sD7OLC1jxJMjjSBr@ATlqLZNjRVo4i8Zhf44dcaJccSCeARmtSXNkecfbs19gzwPORyYncAV7nAm2h7lKhlPB/uj6ZfiVJI13@yPql6GT1PBsQ/wNMh15Rhkz6pe@Bllz7Jy1NzjvznXwN9jTzVpfZ8wTJlfwN/gT7DrJaEe5Ij9wTchaz@bckJb6t4y9l@loPMAeXlD2AtsuWofmgjoq0Al8E3LJbywZ9dUZTgnT6VjOF@2NvYyYY5y7iIfjG3ta2APJGN8zxvTJ3@BPsJcXexcZY3qG48HkBvY8NNg/9jEyfBIm/wZ/gj0PLcHhpCJ@jd2TIziBvYzwTpj3MD1vXfOQ3NEWOvrkrvV@ho9C7rCHDv33BBmtyzLG7v1q38uwDTgzZOxXZOxR5IH@Z6DPwdlExl7EdNweYM/nQNvEWJwHbHI0xI92NNDfDum2YMydnMAZ7D43j8aI6fSdwRX8Df4EuyPQUyBT8azGiIK9iAJfggKnvOkYnsAN7HkOCc/C7QhOeJMH2PUTCuThnBQq4pQ9F5w1XGfzy1720OFo1eFIpTZYcNYwndC/wZ9gjxN7FAVjd4kJ4agjnEEU7FdMj88IlnyB71dF3uCahXG2wA@hpAe@YCgjzhomf4M/wV5G@CoUnDVMTuAM/gZ/ghVnhQzqBfsD87WXXl6s/QvG3@ukH/zVmJcDnkXbyeqLCtb@kwvY9ZN1Xlzg21BygQxsMqMd5QH5gXRRrqK9ncledvgzTPb4sd6fnsEBnMANrLTUZxas9wvW@OullM4NeUO56OpXYVcVbaeij8KaumCcLVVnaqVWyFc4Izak1RB/R7rwQsQ4WzDOlgabaVqjlaYzxPVKR7DrBGvqAn@DgvOF6Zmdwd9gyaAuGtoOXAZLqwhHG2kV8aDfa2g7OHcoGMcLzhcK1uAF43iB70HBOF7ge1CwBp8XKSJYz6Lv6hk@oxnPok11tKkOPXTYZEd5e4O8xtbStU4p44FXKuxzhDf2vA3tKU32sg/020P7DOddDIfRH8InYV7gyOBvsOthdMSvc40yWBbti9ZH@yT1kd1WnFlMHmD3jIWvQsX8YbK8cjPCCxx3VUeTlZ@KZzUfnhdQvsHyBe6IX3ZYcZZRg/rAirOMirV/DeobJ1cwZRRPgnxCeEb8OvuomHvUoH5yXo7JYMWjPb2KecV6WaAznJCD9sQq7hDUqDGuRs3/K/wcJn@BPX7sIZx3gjjrWdQp/Bkq/Bkq9hDmZZ0EHmAve@xIi@VSP1xxflGxxq/wjaxJbe28x@RwwbMV8tB/ani2vYV7WbCur/CHrPCBnG8eKWCPJ2vvosIvYn7weNL8vJpjDI6pCYejT1hs3gy4oeURBhfwjWab/ux/hDe0KTU/XLZfXY@N6Bh8SWDLLdgzv76sfLmBIeMuGrbeF@Hs28f3u3KHO9Iayk58ronbcp96wM35TmVsuUB1565nw20e@6VpCWzOCfIZrHxOFyXPg2//bfZ0fXlgy@XI5f1I0pYLUQRLPiuffqxoy4XIyxs7nu14dkBedTHdhrwsKSrPKb2xl9GP92y5B4kb4oFuM@ooJ8ln6HC@Rd65Kp9@BcaWy46XvTzSW3lU9oJ6hOFPlx1P111zbLnCeHhVS5quMJ5uhU5qVD1WxFORZ79AYsvdpIIVPt7Yy96C0vKp5P5OYgAz/BPsttpQR60i/qb8uGvp5gZWnNB5h847dO4uI7ZcQBrY0@3QT2@yya5OT24fBrcPW@/0cDsZaMujQl62nR7lc3JzDpCRPcgVY3/hvjor/@lRnc7XwhXnjvDhdTRdKMjdObpdJZ9e3C/Tiz3dgLyhz0khu86TXzzc7OUNyCf6ooS@KAXoDf3zdK3I4E9n9VfThULy6ivkNrFZMsh/zAiv0nlUe5SrwWaXT9BJUhuc3MCSL9J5qni2Q2ZAZqhestrj5A72@srQQ1a/reP/zV9gyaPsGL5T7giHjRXo368umL@/5bLbhrsk2n2VoLPCq/Jc1KZ0DL@/qerpVrSpCp1U9UWpqs1O9nKhz0wV9VXzm4zi0RiX0Mfq2Pt@qf0y7Ad97DzeDuAO1vQK/UND/9BQv@7iv7/ILpmG@KG31iEPHfpx9f1S@2XYfFdfl9Cvpo423tHGu@ZxqaO9d7T33lXvA@n6snNzB7sOB2zVXeT319MbWPJqU/mR/vMj/edHfeD8MrrCVe/zKPdxbq7z/CitjLncfD/PzVtG35uDxpQcNL5nzPdySAhX@53HwJLRnCeHinDZQA4d8Ujn2bdu99fKG9hn8bFBRnWXo/oBHZ0ajkI3e1pJfVdO6n@yL4cMx5ybJVOUhyS7mkeVAezPZvXJOavt56x5iI4kDUeJ@4u8AezlwvxtsperwE7QL@X6gAM4vrHnrWrMyuhbdPxm6/iN3MAD7HmrqJeG/GNulhvsCn1IRh9y3ym0uSC8gjU3nsdOCVx9Gai@uvi1E8ORz@biXPCsbLI8HfLSQ8G6qQTEH2Rv8xgmgpNzQbhsrASNffP4xOOMqseCdVCJBTKypRIZj8YFHWMYji5sHSe4fKqQR3mT7K348t7WUYHHk6GTrHFkbvF73nJDuPqxgrYwt/Wdsd6Z7@rxdAt0XtQGS5GNzS1713MpkEF5C3RYtF6Y2/TijmdhD6UjP5pPzu17fxbrqYL2WNAeS9Uac74jKIIVT3ljc0Z9ubvbZpfH5kZpGndK09y7YD1VGmy1QQ9d7bp05L9HyKAuuvr80jXn0Ra2YUt6s5erQ7cdNtyH7A3j@NyGDmAv44CdjAQZzc3mNnQAe/5HRVqwDXe1t7Xd7NtJ6HPqozG3PuoD57ZvcG5vfMs4t2jJHn@Q3VaMv9XfurJZ8lrXzC1RMeLEOmWy5zOqj6oR6WLsrhiX7zuINmv@U5P2QGrSeqomlDHFN/4DlrzsqibtcVX0VzVp/lkxdq@vMYAVPt7G6Bke14t/6uGC8LHGdFv859fuueanStoJs1/Dw4aHnV3vgx5aFVo9NEUPPYfGcW9zfgk9NCs0K1RZyMrDud190EMVQ1EMRTkryllVHqryUFW2qrJVqaZKN015aMpDUwxNMTQoFzF0hXYP7SpFVym64u2Kd0i/Q/odSm0otfA84KTqelChQSUJrF3U6XwdwxdY4bCRqELMVycoHPIR8gn5SZBPSAu2EnJAeEQ44oEVzT1qGe0DhnxBeUtDOPIMWwkV8Ve2BDYFlAVmdK@dX3aZhmcbnoUBhY6yd@Qf1hI65Ed4Y5c5V6bj2YeXDPJwrklfzuB@eO7Jf4E/weZcIVMhozLGIGM@HztxdpmoujtfMHKWTAKr7u4V2Xj2vb/An2DJ8NkB@SF5dFoxI57cEN7ewj3OgjyjQ7t73ZclkyCTIIM8FOShdIR3haPru/vkmwvCy1u45wG2fa9oxrMf7jIN5Wqo04Y6bajThnpB93mvZcaz7y0ZlKuhXB3poi1E9JexI56OeDrjUb8U0avGgTgHnh14dkgP6VGdpkd1OveiXSaoLlJQXdwXB24O4AhO4IJ4CuJBftB2EtpOQttJsUKmQqYjXOVNHOBTRLh0ldCfJ7SphDaV0KZSRpwZcWbEg3Z091QvuzzaVEKbuvuo8eydfoElA30W6LMgXbSvhPaVKuqroiwVZamox4o8VOQB7TGhPSa0wYQ2mDA3uVeG4tkX/QJ/giWTIJMgg7w15A3tNKGdJsx5EsasewUonn3RL7DCoasOXXXUF8a1u0e6GO3uXkeJZx9SjAkmxqmMceruQ16WjPSZA@IJiCcgHkyHc6iQqZBRfeUofeYofWa0x4z2mBPymZDP837Dyxl8x@uMMSVj5npfPrqn2qrHgjF6ugKLO@bjCM@YkXN2XlUXBf3/@nqvM@btyE9B33vXnvGsAcUdrPqqCTIpgBFPamDEc97nfHmAp0yan5o588931ktV00f39ddkPTsgP/773/8H)

Comment: Can you add mod (%)?

Comment: @Fmbalbuena Running

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 8271 bytes, n=2, [by Fmbalbuena](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269298/25180)

```
/~-/-~~//-~/~\--//-*///*\*/76543//~~~~~~~~~~~~%%%/*2*//~///*///%/4//-//~~~--********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************%%%
             ^                                     ^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7cs7CoBADEXR1aQJhAd@N2NjIVjYTZ@tj9HKLQj3QEKKm3bt7Txa78pQZKqWcouowyX55lqXeRql/DAz@VBBPk2NaaqPN4pwAAAAAAAAAAAAAADwe2bW@w0)

#### Alternative solution

```
/~-/-~~//-~/~%--//-*///*\*/76543//~~~~~~~~~~~~%%%/***//~///*///%/4//-//2/~--********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************%%%
                                                                       ^^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7cwxCoBADETR06QJhAFd9TI2FoKF3fa5@ho7ryD8BwlTTNLvo19nH0MZikzVUlpEBZfku2tblzZL@WFmcq9Cvp0aU6sLaao/4QAAAAAAAAAAAAAA4PfMbIwH)

Not a good choice of language.

Comment: Seems it better to place `^` in same codeblock otherwise they scroll to different position

Comment: The first one is my intended solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269337/76323), 5204 bytes

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
string secret = "secret";
void f1(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1111111";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"611111";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1111111";return;}}}}}}}}
void f2(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1111111";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1111111";return;}}}}}}}}
void f3(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1111111";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1111111";return;}}}}}}}}
void f4(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1111111";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1111111";return;}}}}}}}}
void f5(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1111111";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1111111";return;}}}}}}}}
void f6(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1111111";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1111111";return;}}}}}}}}
void f7(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1111111";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1111111";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1111111";return;}}}}}}}}
int main() {
    f1();
    /*();
    f3();
    f4();
    f5();
    f6();
    f7();
    cout<<6;
    f1();
    f2();
    f3();
    f4();
    f5();
    f6();
    f7(*/
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7ZhNb6MwEIb3zK9ws9IWGroNbUIPxv0jEQcgkJoPm8@VKspvz47tQKFSV9ojqn2I3pmXGYbhuYSoLO/PUXS5/KQsyrtTjDzKm7aOg@LF6BrKzogFRdyUQRSjpj1hA0yRbeKojltE0EapDTb@cHpCiWNaPU1Mlf2dx@zcvprWDXGtPuJd63kbR50Nhgu6muGBshYFR9cnvao67vz7W3RrXyNnET0uoqdFtF9EBxkNOOG1KW5ByQ5T74DpditHDI7UfyHwu3X8aTj3x6fhhmW5uyj3yO79XfaBmq8fcNbDgR4ETNVmzKcEhsCpctK5k5EUnEw52dzJSQZOrpx87hQkB6dQTjF3GCnAYcph8kEgG8rdUzu1Mzu3C5sNOOQ8R2/BG0mCvImnFXKYn3um43muhfm8cwlOOTrl2DloukKsTdxEyfH6CnQF26yu2@S/RG1lWb2o2cJrqXwgIzHLyQilEUpDOLI5EVmrF6O2dRfjENDNlA85KPqIb2Tiy3ekzpXix3VT/C8CNcXfhuInTbGmePUU7zXFmuLVU3zQFGuKV0@xqynWFK@e4mdNsaZ4xRTLBQaUmRbqDQRHfHXDUj3cjUr8@7uq/aQOk3In9TwqdVsXf2opPob8d8u7B2O4XP4C)

Can't hack without `\0`

---

For someone trying to solve in intended way:

- You are supposed to choose 6 elements from [1,111]
- For each set of 6 elements in [1,111], there's non-empty subset of both, whose sum is same
- Then I don't know if any conclusion used
- [Searched](https://tio.run/##jVVrb@I4FP1MfsUVFaukDY/QTgeVpFKldmYrMQVBu/3QVsiJHWpInDQJGo12@OvDXuedltldBME@9xznvmw7YdhdOc5@f8SF420pAzNOKA96r5dKBdk8iVlSR0gS@Ny5VErIjJlPwtcgYiiFCnYdkXhNKP4R9@OEJB9R3yeiiW4FR3@kN8oRZS4XDO7g8@CsnIURF4mr9no9Ddx8ggoWRTosl39dLa/mXxfLpaagBXzCharB30pLzlwKFgQhE2q77zPKCT77j1zQ4HvcXSyu@5sNIT2bi7YO0@X8@nGuw@D87EwbKy3nlUTHQCiNcA01nWnofajePUwmOhgT0zwd6jCbT@@Xj/Pb@xv4mU3mN1fXOny7mi0Xf17Nb3DsUlxWrpl73@6Ez/KVcnEJYzQXF1m@TS8Qq0vAlOJbB2Po98E4PzPOh6NPw88Ao8FodDoaDZTWURiRlU8g8EMISUQ8j3ngBhE4geeRMGbqJ01pSUCVmSCWMQZiWkP8OzkhaYYqq22REzTYpmGkdjuzVwTHsiXBKQhOTqgY1HIkgxYMWjAqCrOopLCCwkpKaytivhKMQhjEMt2ka2hwDEh8mGT/jedJLoPyY/8vlvMfdvpbCxvnUL@fFRHU9gx9/fjpeFvo0LS@GAwWWSukHEWy5E@Iv2DsMo8iwawGIuFiy8awS5n10joRT7hDvHyJVvnyRUKiBDqntP/up3aMoUe150g2mG7rjk51pqevKj0pS@JaTJbENa28Jm5Vk6wts4PBvLsEW1bGKJZo4fSnJUHTBHIQtQ@izkGUHkTZQdStoU@Dl3SjFMgHp18bTpeBc7kfeNGJvBY17rj3Sca8Nr4XxSDbxWWSXZ1rlSfF@TVTQ/1NjzR451qInr3hofEmY4rG8Fwqs1ZRQ/gDI9Z6RPxQNa1qk5I3U22uY4g6cK0EyxDXFpe1XRdBrmXLoWSNEpStK0ml2VhrqdkUmk2u2aAGdZuaphJ51kaKvELk5SIPRSj06qJK5VueVPmFys9VPqpQ6TdUlUxYvpSJsmNFrhOoQ61o6lqrIAkA74pxA94pv5nUxtWwHJWDslvSawJiQZ6M4eil1obFRSWIDu3FdPJwfzu9W3bou2@zf2rd8@V2cnOM9x02iZveYNlK3@12jVRch26Ipk6MiyGrbne8AG8CN6y35b@cLtXx8iXYCgqdOO3wxqI7mc2LYlpkpDzXatsts6VP@cDfTtnt978c1yOreN@dnu67aWx@@A8) for one day and get [`,>@Vn~`](https://tio.run/##7ZhLb6MwEIDv@RVuKrWg0CrkQQ/G0f6KvUQcgEBqHjbPShVl/3p2bAcWDpX20AuSfYhm5mPGjvlOhEXxcg3D2@2RsjBrLxFyKa@bKvLz06qtKbsi5udRXfhhhOrmglcARbWOwipqEEFr6/TrN/uzxqsPTi8otg2zo7Gh@GsWsWvzbpgPxDG7kLeN665ttdYYHmgrhnvKGuSfHY90quu89V6e0bN1z@xZtptl@1l2mGVHmfU45pUhtqBki6l7xHSzkUf0z9Q7Efjd2N73h@vn7c6s3SXbry85B3r@a4YNMwhANWaoJwQOgRNFkilJSQIkVSSdkoykQDJFsinJSQYkVySfEkZyIEwRJv8IVAN599RKrNTKrNxiPQ44z9Cn/0liP6uj8Qo5nJ@7hu26jon5dHIBpBhIMUz26zYX1yY2UeHwfAlxCbdZ3m@TP4ne0jQ70bOB11J6YEZsFCMIJAgkEEQOJ6JqduKoTdVGOAB1U8WhBk3/8gdZ@PYdqXW3eKct1hYv3uK9tlhbvHiLD9pibfHiLT5qi7XFi7fY0RZrixdv8Zu2WFu8YIvlBfqUGSbqVgiW@OqGVbQbo/0YHcboOEbOGL0NkdrWwT80sr/d/gI)
- Confirmed unique. `time` result `895471.99user 2246.72system 28:27:01elapsed 876%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 411544maxresident)k 2352inputs+1721048outputs (229024major+17451minor)pagefaults 0swaps`

Answer (score 0):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 4960 bytes, cracks [dfe dfe's cop](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269212/92727)

Sorry for the unintended solution ): I'll try to find the intended one, it seems interesting.
This only used 4 changes, if you must use all 6 than you can just change the comment.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
string secret = "secret";
void f1(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"6";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1";return;}}}}}}}}
void f2(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1";return;}}}}}}}}
void f3(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1";return;}}}}}}}}
void f4(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1";return;}}}}}}}}
void f5(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1";return;}}}}}}}}
void f6(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1";return;}}}}}}}}
void f7(){if(secret.length()!=6){cout<<"1";return;}int a[6]={secret[0]-' ',secret[1]-' ',secret[2]-' ',secret[3]-' ',secret[4]-' ',secret[5]-' '};for(int i=0;i<5;i++){if(a[i]>=a[i+1]){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=0;i<6;i++){if(a[i]<=0||a[i]>111){cout<<"1";return;}}for(int i=1;i<=111;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<=111;j++){for(int k=j+1;k<=111;k++){for(int l=k+1;l<=111;l++){for(int m=l+1;m<=111;m++){for(int n=m+1;n<=111;n++){int b[6]={i,j,k,l,m,n};bool yay=false;for(int o=1;o<(1<<6);o++){for(int p=1;p<(1<<6);p++){int asum=0;int bsum=0;for(int q=0;q<6;q++){if(o&(1<<q)){asum+=a[q];}if(p&(1<<q)){bsum+=b[q];}}if(asum==bsum){yay=true;break;}}if(yay){break;}}if(!yay){cout<<"1";return;}}}}}}}}
int main() {f1();}//);f3();f4();f5();f6();f7();cout<<6;f1();f2();f3();f4();f5();f6();f7();}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7ZjbbqMwEEDf8xVuKm1Bodu4bejD4P5IxAMhkDUXm@tKFeXbs2M7SUFqPwCt8xB55njGxhxFhLiqHk9xfD7fcxEX/TEhAZdt1yRR@b7qWy5ORERl0lZRnJC2O8IKocq2SdwkHWFkbUZrWP2V/EhS6rgDTx2T/V0k4tT9cdw75rtDLPsuCNZ0DYj6RsDIRUeivR@ywczfb8PHB/LgXSI6i55n0cssep1FOx2NkMrGUUtwtgUe7IBvNnpz0Z6H7wy/NzS8bcv/2tY4L/RnhQHbfn7qDpTS7y5qUk2xmuE00@CazxguDJkh2ZTkLEOSG5JPScFyJIUhxZSUrEBSGlJOiWAlEmGI0JeA2YM@b@5lXu4VXumJEQ5SFuQj@mBpVLTJ7dgk7l8GDg0C3wU57Vwhqa6kunaO2r5UB6YWMcPr/BrHNZ5jfTlH@UvV1q47qJoN3oo6RBtSp7qBgwYHDRTRzZnKuoPaatf0CRxQ1NxwzGHRV3ynE9/cHfO52Pq8VFuptfX/s/XF2mptXYytr9ZWa@tibN1ZW62ti7HVt7ZaWxdj65u11dq6AFv10UVcOC4Z1IssGJ@eXFB/u0A9zYJ6SAD12wtKaTCNfNBT1auEn6eO5/M/)

Comment: Can you cheat if all `"1"` replaced with `"111111111111111111"`?